# Biweekly View with DHTMLX Gantt Chart

Tags: javascript, date, dhtmlx

In my dhtmlx gantt chart, I've configured my scales to show the year and Quarter (3 PIs per quarter)

```
gantt.config.scales = [
    { name: 'year', format: '%Y' },
    { name: 'quarter', template: date => `PI-${(Math.floor((new Date(date).getMonth() / 3)) + 1 )}` },
]
```

This gives me the result

```
|             2022             |
|   PI-1  |   PI-2   |  PI-3   |
```

I now want to add 2-week increments to my scale to represent sprints per Quarter (6 sprints per quarter, 24 sprints per year)

```
|             2022             |
|  PI-1   |   PI-2   |  PI-3   |
| S1 | S2 | S3 |  S4 | S5 | S6 |
```

I can't figure out how to structure my template to achieve this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that if the increment is 2 weeks, then there will be more than 24 sprints in a year. The same can be said about months, one quarter is equal to 3 months, which contain a non-integer number of weeks, so the boundaries of the quarter and sprint scales cannot coincide.
To set sprints in the scale, you need to use [`Custom time units`](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__configuring_time_scale.html#:%7E:text=Custom-,time%20units,-dhtmlxGantt%20allows%20you).
And so I can offer the following solution:

If the increment is to be strictly 2 weeks, first determine the start date of each sprint. It is also necessary to set the start for the first sprint, for example, I set it to start on Monday of the first week of the year:

```
// specify the start date of the first sprint
gantt.config.project_start = new Date(2022, 0, 3);

// find a sprint for a given date
function findSprint(date) {
    const firstSprint = gantt.date.week_start(new Date(gantt.config.project_start));
    let currentDate = firstSprint;
    let direction = 1;

    if (date < firstSprint) {
        direction = -1;
    }
    const increment = 2 * direction;

    let nextDate = gantt.date.add(currentDate, increment, "week");
    let num = 0;
    
    while (!(currentDate.valueOf() <= date.valueOf() && nextDate.valueOf() > date.valueOf())) {
        if (increment > 0) {
            currentDate = nextDate;
            nextDate = gantt.date.add(currentDate, increment, "week");
        } else {
            nextDate = currentDate;
            currentDate = gantt.date.add(currentDate, increment, "week");
        }
        num += 1 * direction;
    }

    return {
        sprintStart: currentDate,
        sprintEnd: nextDate,
        sprintNumber: num
    }
}

// custom scale unit definition
gantt.date.sprint_start = function (date) {
    return findSprint(date).sprintStart;
};
```

The next step is to specify that the increment will be two weeks:

```
gantt.date.add_sprint = function (date, inc) {
    return gantt.date.add(gantt.date.sprint_start(date), inc * 2, "week");
};
```

And finally, add a new unit to the scale:

```
gantt.config.scales = [
    { unit: "year", step: 1, format: "%Y" },
    {
        unit: 'quarter',
        format: date => {
            return `PI-${(Math.floor((new Date(date).getMonth() / 3)) + 1)}`
        }
    },
    { unit: 'sprint', step: 1, template: function (date) {
            const sprintInfo = findSprint(date);
            return `Sprint ${sprintInfo.sprintNumber + 1}, (${gantt.templates.date_grid(sprintInfo.sprintStart)} - ${gantt.templates.date_grid(new Date(sprintInfo.sprintEnd - 1))})`
        }
    }
];
```

Please see an example: https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/15u2bd85.

Sometimes for some reason the borders of the quarter and year scales do not match, and this is most likely a bug, if this happens to you, please contact dhtmlx technical support.

If you want to have 24 sprints in a year, you can set specific dates for each sprint, it might look something like this:

```
const sprints = [
    { name: 'S1',  start_date: new Date(2022,00,01), end_date: new Date(2022,00,15) },
    { name: 'S2',  start_date: new Date(2022,00,15), end_date: new Date(2022,01,01) },
    { name: 'S3',  start_date: new Date(2022,01,01), end_date: new Date(2022,01,15) },
    { name: 'S4',  start_date: new Date(2022,01,15), end_date: new Date(2022,02,01) },
    { name: 'S5',  start_date: new Date(2022,02,01), end_date: new Date(2022,02,15) },
    { name: 'S6',  start_date: new Date(2022,02,15), end_date: new Date(2022,03,01) },
    ...
];
```

You need to add the given sprints to the unit:

```
gantt.date.sprints_start = function(date) {
    return date;
};

function getSprint(date,type) {
    const tempDate = new Date(date);

    for (let i = 0; i < sprints.length; i++) {
        if (+tempDate >= +sprints[i].start_date && +tempDate < +sprints[i].end_date) {
            if (type == 'scaleUnit') {
                return sprints[i].end_date;
            }

            if (type == 'template') {
                return "<div class='sprint'>"+sprints[i].name+"</div>";
            }
        }
    }

    if (type == 'scaleUnit') {
        const newDate = gantt.date.add(date, 1,'day');

        return newDate;
    }

    if (type == 'template') {
        return gantt.date.date_to_str("%m-%d")(date);
    }
}

gantt.date.add_sprints = function(date, inc) {
    return getSprint(date, 'scaleUnit');
};

const sprintsTemplate = function(date) {
    return getSprint(date,'template');
}
```

and also add a new unit to the scale:

```
gantt.config.scales = [
    { unit: "year", step: 1, format: "%Y" },
    {
        unit: 'quarter',
        format: date => {
            return `PI-${(Math.floor((new Date(date).getMonth() / 3)) + 1 )}`
        }
    },
    { unit: 'month', step: 1, format: "%M" },
    { unit: 'sprints', step: 1, template: sprintsTemplate },
];
```

Here is an example: https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/0xznw5m9